Why am I getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver when using a custom class loader?
This works with Java 8:
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], null);
    System.out.println("" + loader.loadClass("java.sql.Driver"));
  }
}

But throws ClassNotFoundException with Java 17:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)

Great diagram explaining class loaders (Java 9+):
https://medium.com/@wakefulinsomnia/how-does-java-classloader-system-work-82eaf378f73b
Related/similar issues:

https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/discussions/5079
https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/issues/4719
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
https://github.com/kscripting/kscript/issues/163


My current understanding is that if a null parent is used, really only the java base classes plus the classes in the URL[] parameter will be available.
If 'non-basic' classes from modules like 'java.sql' are also required, then at least the platform classloader needs to be used as parent.
ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader() is available since Java 9, as pointed out by @VGR.
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    System.out.println("java.version                                              : " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
    System.out.println("Test.class.getClassLoader()                               : " + Test.class.getClassLoader());
    System.out.println("ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()                        : " + ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    System.out.println("ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()            : " + ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());
    System.out.println("ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader()                      : " + ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader());
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader());
    System.out.println("loader.loadClass('java.sql.Driver')                       : " + loader.loadClass("java.sql.Driver"));
  }
}

Output:
java.version                                              : 17.0.8
Test.class.getClassLoader()                               : jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()                        : jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()            : jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader@30f39991
ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader()                      : jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader@30f39991
loader.loadClass('java.sql.Driver')                       : interface java.sql.Driver


ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent() is an unreliable hack.  Did you happen to try ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader() as the parent?

@VGR No, thanks for the tip!

We still compile with Java 8, which is probably why I didn't see that method. But for modern Java this is definitely the way to go.

Or you use java.sql.Driver.class.getClassLoader() as the parent loader…
